# Best Authetication between REST API and Mobile App

Tags: rest-api, authentication

I am developing a mobile app, with WordPress REST API.

What is the recommended authentication method and plugin to use for?

here the list I found:

- [OAuth 1.0a](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-oauth1)
- [OAuth 2.0](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider)
- [JWT Authentication](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)
- [Two-Factor Authentication](https://wordpress.org/plugins/application-passwords)

Comment: JWT seems very popular because of scalability and easeness of deployment, as it is more standardized the way you do things than OAuth that admits disparate implementations. JWT could be considered in some way a standardized implementation of TFA.

Comment: Yeah, after trying the OAuth, I ended up using JWT for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT Authentication is very Popular and easy to config. For Two Factor Authentication use this [JWT Athhentication Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) .